# what would be the phenomena used to generate electricty

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

what phenomena would be used to in generating electricity like if a kids hanging rattle works on simple pendulum motion to what would be the phenomena or what would be the principal in generating it?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to generate electricity is through Induction or Faraday's Law of Magnetic Induction. What happens is a magnet or current is passed through a surface. The change in flux over time induces a voltage on the surface. If you look up this law you will get an equation for EMF. Imagine a wire curled around a magnet, and being turned around it. Such an action would create a voltage in the wire, due to the flux changing in parts of the wire, and causing a voltage.